# [...]のあの[...] Meaning and valid usage

Tags: particle-の

I am reading the Japanese translation of Matilda. Spoilers ahead.

Matilda is deciding to take revenge on her father for his "attitude in front of the TV". She says:

> テレビの前でのあの態度にはお返しをしなければならない。

「テレビの前でのあの態度」 throws me off. I would have thought this only to work if we had 「テレビの前の態度」, or alternatively put some kind of verb after で.

Is this のあの construct common? How should I parse it? I'm assuming it means "that attitude", "such an attitude" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction isn't のあの; rather, it's テレビの前での followed by あの.

In English prepositional phrases can modify nouns as in:

> "his attitude in front of the tv"

But in Japanese テレビの前で alone cannot modify a noun.

By adding の to テレビの前で, it can then modify 態度.

あの態度 means "his attitude".

If you dropped で then you loose the spacial aspect of what's being expressed.  で informs you about where the father is displaying his attitude.  If you just said, テレビの前の態度, then this sounds like you're talking about the *attitude of the front of the TV*.

So there are two modifiers here for 態度

- あの  meaning essentially "his" or "that"
- テレビの前での "in front of the TV"

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am still confused as to what のあの means, and why 前での is used instead of 前の態度. I presume this is because one means "the attitude in front of the TV" and the other means "the attitude [displayed] in front of the TV".

Comment: @doliphin I've updated the answer.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: While your answer is correct, most native speakers would understand テレビの前の態度 the same way as テレビの前での態度.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you for the feedback.  I'd wondered about that...  But would a native speaker actually say テレビの前の態度?

Comment: I would, and I might even say テレビの前であの態度 but this is a "lazy" version of テレビの前であの態度（を取ること） and gives an impression that where the person displayed said attitude is important, rather than the attitude itself.